# Where can the original paper by Takagi in English be found?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

As we all know, the theory of class fields began at the paper by Takagi on the abelian extensions of the field of rational numbers. Then one naturally has the following

> Where can one find the English version of that paper, or had this paper been translated into English yet?

Thanks.

Comment: Hum, a quick search doesn't find anything. This [1950s MR review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=54644) of Takagi's monograph (not the paper, which is not even in the MR database) expressed hope that the monograph would be translated to a western European language. As far as I know, it hasn't happened.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked $11$ years ago, but as of recent the only things I could find of Takagi's works that have been translated to English from what can be seen in the previews are the following:

1. [Teiji Takagi's Collected Papers, (Springer Collected Works in Mathematics) $2$nd ed. $1990$ Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4431549943)
2. [Teiji Takagi's Collected Papers, Paperback – Nov. $3$, $2014$](https://www.amazon.ca/Collected-Papers-Teiji-Takagi/dp/4431549943)

Before at all purchasing the books, because they are rather expensive, it would be worthwhile to double check the bibliography using the "Look Inside" feature in the site to double-check the works you want are there, as there are a ton of Takagi's other works there, and it would be also worthwhile to message the publishers by emailing Springer [here](https://support.springer.com/en/support/solutions/articles/6000206179-contact-us) to double-check if the parts we cannot preview (and the parts you want) have been actually translated. Otherwise, if you can get a copy Takagi's paper on the abelian extensions of the field of rational numbers, then it is possible to request/pay a translation site to translate the document for you. Most sites it's \$$0.10$ cost per word to be translated, so do plan accordingly.